How to style elements in shadow root?
I have the following html
<tag>
  #shadow-root
     <slot name="avatar"></slot>
     <span class="label"><spot></spot></slot>
  Test
</tag>

How can I style the "label" element with css outside the tag component?

this is invalid HTML, you didn't copy/paste your HTML?

The Web Component Author decides which parts of shadowDOM can be styled with the part="thelabel" attribute
The Component User can then style shadowDOM content with the ::part(thelabel) selector
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/::part
Parts and Slots are unrelated other then being inside shadowDOM.
Also see my (very long) answer on :slotted


<my-element>
  <!-- Web Component with Declarative ShadowRoot, without JavaScript -->
  <template shadowrootmode="open">
     <style>
      .label {
        border: 2px dashed red;
      }
     </style>
     <slot name="avatar"></slot>
     <span part="thelabel" class="label">A Label</span>
  </template>
  <span slot="avatar">Avatar goes here</span>
</my-element>

<style>
  my-element::part(thelabel) {
    border-color: green;
  }
  span {
    background: pink; 
  }
</style>



